# file upload with spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

I am uploading file using spring MVC and jquery. Inside my class method I have written

```
    @RequestMapping(value="attachFile", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<FileAttachment> upload(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession session) {
    String fileName =  null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;


    //Save the file to a temporary location 

    ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();
    String realContextPath = context.getRealPath("/");

    fileName =  realContextPath +"/images/"+file.getOriginalFilename();


    //File dest = new File(fileName);

    try {

        //file.transferTo(dest);

        inputStream = file.getInputStream();
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);



        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Its uploading the file correctly I am using

```
   ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();
   String realContextPath = context.getRealPath("/");
```

to get the path. My first question is , Is this the correct way to get the path and it stores the file somewhere at 
                      workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myproject/images

and when I am trying to display this image on my jsp page using the following code

```
<img src="<%=request.getRealPath("/") + "images/images.jpg" %>" alt="Upload Image" />
```

It does not display the image, Its generating the following html

```
 <img src="/home/name/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myproject/images/images.jpg" alt="Upload Image">
```

Am I doing the things right? In my project I have to upload large number of files everyday.

Please let me know if you need anything else to understand my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better if you upload your files in some directory by absolute path(e.g. `C:\images\`) instead of relative (your approach). Usually, web apps runs on linux mathines on production and it is good practice to make save path configurable.

Create some application property which will holds save path for files(in xml or property file).

Comment: Hi vacuum, thanks for your response. I tried to test this and modify my code with this fileName =  "/Home/images/"+file.getOriginalFilename(); then I am getting the error  /Home/images/images.jpg (No such file or directory). I have created a inages folder in my home folder on ubuntu

Comment: Can you try /home/images (note the lower case h in home)?

Comment: Above error is solved my path was incorrect. If I have to download or display the uploaded file then how can I do that just giving the path is not working.

Comment: if you on Windows, try: `fileName = "C:\Home\images\"+file.getOriginalFilename();`

Comment: @user965884 did you have images dir in home?

Comment: yes, I can store images in my home/images folder. I am using ubuntu

Comment: On my jsp page I am using <img src="<%="/home/images/image.jpg" %>" alt="Upload Image" /> but its not displaying image

Comment: On browser its giving error GET http://localhost:8080/home/images/images.jpg 404 (Not Found). Does that mean I can't access my files from home folder. Do I need to save them on server then?